# Create a fixed size section with gcc and place values in it

Tags: c, gcc, linker, binaryfiles

I need to embed a binary file within an executable generated with `gcc` on Linux, to be executed in the host (not in a separated device).

In addition, I want to be able to change that binary content externally by using `obcjcopy --update-section`.

I could do that with `__attribute__(("section"))`, but the problem is that the mentioned binary file might have different sizes at different moments, so I want to allocate a section of a fixed maximum size. Thus, I can update slightly bigger/smaller binaries in the future.

Apart from the above, I would like to give a default value to that particular section at build time (a predefined binary file that is available at build time).

This can be done with a linker script. However, as far as I understand, I would need to modify the OS default linker script, what I want to avoid.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to create an array on that section with a fixed size, using the first bytes for allocating the default binary file and padding the rest with `0xFF`'s for instance.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Re "*but the problem is that the mentioned binary file might have different sizes at different moments*", Not sure how that's a problem. `const char img[MAX_SIZE] __attribute__((section ("img"))) = { 1,2,3,0 };`

Comment: do you mean inside the code area? something like `void blank(void) { goto ENDBLANK; asm("nop;nop;nop;nop;"); ENDBLANK: return; }` *or whatever the syntax is*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ikegami has mentioned, it's enough to specify the maximum size of the array and then initialise the values you need.